# How to add multiple different text views in linear layout

Tags: android

Hi I was want to add 2 different text views to my linear layout but somehow when i try to add both of them only the first one appears why is this the case? Here is my code :

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // create the text view for the main string to
    // be displayed
    TextView displayMainText = new TextView(this);
    displayMainText.setTextSize(15);
    displayMainText.setText(mainString);
    displayMainText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    displayMainText.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

    // Create the text view for the optional string to
    // be displayed
    TextView displayOppText = new TextView(this);
    displayOppText.setTextSize(15);
    displayOppText.setText(optionalString);
    displayOppText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    displayOppText.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);

    // add text views to the layout
    LinearLayout studyTLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.study_time_layout);
    studyTLayout.addView(displayMainText);
    studyTLayout.addView(displayOppText);
    setContentView(studyTLayout);
```

With my code it only adds the first text view correctly

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you didn't set the orientation of the `LinearLayout` to Vertical.

```
studyTLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```